# Ошибки проверки вебмастером

Tags: robots.txt

Ошибки при индексировании, вызванные внутренними (дочерними) страницами сайта, можно исправить, добавив нужные страницы их в robots.txt
Есть ли похожее решение для страниц, которые не являются дочерними (сторонние ресурсы)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect 301` в `.htaccess` для битых ссылок.